# GET not showing the objects Posted which is implemented in java dynamic web project

Tags: java, json, list, post, get

I am implementing(in eclipse) a simple way to put and get using my java api.

The code is as follows:

```
@Path("/jason")
public class JavajsonRestApi {

    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

    @GET
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Book> getJson() {
        return bookList;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Book> postJson(Book book) {
        bookList.add(book);
        return bookList;
    }

}
```

The `bookList` is a global variable declared outside the methods. Using post post I am pushing objects to the specified endpoint. Using get I am getting list of objects from the same end-point.

But the GET show empty list despite adding to the list, moreover `bookList` is global variable here. The GET should show list of books posted.

Why is the weird behavior?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions to this problem I got working was from: https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Implementing-POST-Method/

The code implementation changes to:

```
@Path("/jason")
public class JavajsonRestApi {

private Booklist  bookList = new Booklist();

    @POST
    @Path("/json")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Book postJson(Book book) {
      bookList.addBook(book);
      return book;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Book> getJson() {
        return bookList.getAllBooks();
    }
}
```

The Booklist implementation is:

```
public class Booklist {

private Map<Long, Book> books = Databaseclasss.getBooks();

public Booklist() {
    books.put(1L, new Book("I","you",1));
    books.put(2L, new Book("me","me",2));
}

public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
    return new ArrayList<Book>(books.values());
}

public Book getBook(Long id) {
    return books.get(id);
}

public Book addBook(Book book) {
    book.setid(books.size()+1);
    books.put(book.getId().longValue(), book);
    return book;
}

public Book removeBook(Long id) {
    return books.remove(id);
}
}
```

The Databaseclass implementation is as follows:

```
public class Databaseclasss {

private static Map<Long, Book> books= new HashMap<>();

public static Map<Long, Book> getBooks(){
    return books;
}
}
```

I hope this is helpful to others as well.

Thank you Laurens and Stafs for valuable responses.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of pointers that might help you out;

- Your postJson() should not produce and shouldn't return the list
- Add @Consumes to your postJson()
- Your getJson() should not Consume
- I'd just use the bookList variable you posted instead of the global variable but initialize it properly (private)

That should probably fix your issue, but don't forget to debug! Check the values which your methods return

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I did not completely get the last pointer.Can you please explain the same?

Comment: Pretty sure your JavajsonRestApi persists, i.e. it stays in memory so the variables your create in it stay 'active'. You can add and remove from bookList without having to use a global variable (use getters/setters). I don't know the rest of your code so it might be you overwrite the bookList variable every time, meaning your changes get discarded

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you should return object of javax.ws.rs.core.Response class instead of list of books.
It may look like this:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(bookList).build();
```

Comment: for which method it should be returned? POST or GET method?